# Why cannot run call part in a task scheduler?

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

Here is my case: I edit a batch file and scheduled it in task scheduler. The batch file runs all part except call another batch file. Here is my code sample for batch file:

```
CLS
@Echo off
Rename d:\temp\online.txt online_old.txt
Call D:\temp\sub_batch.bat
```

I can run it successfully in the command window (it will go through the entire batch file). But when I scheduled it in task scheduler. It will skip the call part. Very interesting. Is there anybody met this before and how to fix it?
Thanks,

Comment: What makes you think it skipped it? You are making assumptions here. I suggest you pipe the output to a file and see what is really happening.

Comment: Thanks Nick, Because I can get the result which after call part, and the call part will create a log file which is not created on task scheduler...

Comment: You might find it is created somewhere else. Or you might find that the batch can't complete because the task scheduler account doesn't have sufficient security. It depends on what the batch file does and what security it needs. Are you running as the same user in task scheduler?

Comment: Yes. I run it as the same user in the command window and task scheduler...and the "after call part" need to check the call part's generated file" then go on...

Comment: If you run `D:\temp\sub_batch.bat` on it's own in the task scheduler does it behave as expected? Narrow the problem down.

Comment: Yes. It works in task scheduler. This time I just want to add some additional steps but I don't want to modify the original one. So I use call.

Comment: Hi Nick, I checked the sub_batch.bat. There is also another call level in this file. Is that the cause? Regards,

Comment: Who knows. Which actual bit of your batch file do you think is not working? Test just that bit on it's own and work back from there. I don't have an answer for you at this stage - it could be many things, and if you go through the steps of troubleshooting it yourself you'll find it.

Comment: If `D:\temp\sub_batch.bat` has the command `Exit` in it, change it to `Exit /B`. _Of course, [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49343584/edit) to include the content of `sub_batch.bat` would certainly give us a fighting chance of better isolating your issue._

Comment: If `D:\temp\sub_batch.bat` or its called Batch file create a log file, and the created log file _have **not** an absolute path_, then it is created _in the current directory_. Question: what is the current directory in a Batch file started from task sheduler? (answer: I don't know **;)**

Comment: Is the task configured to run whether user is logged on or not?

Comment: Yes. I SET IT AS "RUN WHETHER USER IS LOGGED OR NOT".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for helping me with this. Here is the resolution:

Set up the task “Start in (optional)” as the batch file located. It impacts call command. The task works fine now.

Regards,

Comment: Yes. This sets the current directory in a Batch file started from task sheduler, as I said in my comment. However, this does _not_ "impacts" the `Call D:\temp\sub_batch.bat` command because it have an absolute path. It impacts _any command_ that include a file name with relative path.